# How can i combine $searchbeta and geo search in mongodb atlas

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

my team migrate data to mongodb atlas.

I have a question.

How can i combine $searchbeta and geo search in mongodb atlas.

Comment: not sure MongoDB Atlas is different for on prem MongoDB! Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: @BookOfZeus I want to search for stores within 1 km of the user, and can search for store names, sorted by store name or distance.

Comment: You should be able to perform the same operations as long you have access and the same data. I recently migrated to MongoDB Atlas and we didn't have any issues running the same actions/queries. If you currently running these queries, try a development instance (it's free i think) import your data and try, you will see right away

Comment: @BookOfZeus My sql like this: db.getCollection('campfire').aggregate([{"$searchBeta":{"search":{"query":["msg"],"path":["title"],"phrase":{"prefix":true}}}},{"$match":{"title":"msg01"}},{"$skip":0},{"$limit":10}]), but query timeout.  You can get result like this?

Comment: @BookOfZeus By the way, i insert 1.5 million test data. This problem was not found when the amount of data was small.

Comment: Query time out means you probably does not use proper index, make sure your indexes looks good. Run an explain() on it to see whats going on: `db.campfire.explain()`

Answer (score 1):

The `$search` (or `$searchBeta`) stage now supports geospatial queries.
Your field that contains geospatial data must be mapped to [geo](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/index-definitions/#geo) type. Then there are a few possible ways to query that data: [near](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/near/#geojson-point-example), [geoWithin](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/geoWithin/) and [geoShape](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/atlas-search/geoShape/).